# How to find iTunes automatic-update status programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, itunes, automatic-updates

Is it possible to find(by programmatically) whether the user enabled the automatic updates on itunes or not?

Comment: No, this is not possible, Apple does not allow you to access these kind of settings.

Comment: Such option is great security risk so no, you can't have such possibility.